# R: Add two data frames with same dimensions

Tags: r

I have df1:

```
Type     CA     AR     Total
alpha    2      3        5
beta     1      5        6
gamma    6      2        8
delta    8      1        9
```

I have df2:

```
Type     CA     AR     Total
alpha    3      4        7
beta     2      6        8
gamma    9      1        10
delta    4      1        5
```

I want to add the values in both the data frames to get 1 data frame with this result:

```
    Type     CA     AR     Total
    alpha    5      7        12
    beta     3      11       14
    gamma    15     3        18
    delta    12     2        14
```

Example --> (alpha, CA) = 2 (from df1) + 3 (from df2) = 5 (resulting df)

Does anyone know how to do this? It's not exactly merge I think because merge will override the value, where as, I want to add the value.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I recognize this data from yesterday... and still think you should use matrices. With those, you can just add `mat1 + mat2`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30488161/1191259

Answer (score 4):

`+` is vectorised, this is just a simple operation in R

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[-1] + df2[-1])
#    Type CA AR Total
# 1 alpha  5  7    12
# 2  beta  3 11    14
# 3 gamma 15  3    18
# 4 delta 12  2    14
```

If your data set are not order properly, you could use `match` (as mentioned in comments)

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[, -1] + df2[match(df1$Type, df2$Type), -1])
```

Comment: @user4918087  Just a warning. Since you mentioned the word merge, if your row orders are not the same, you need a different answer probably with `match`

Comment: @Vlo if the aren't ordered, I would just do `df1[order(df1[, 1]), -1] + df2[order(df2[, 1]), -1]`

Comment: That works. Was thinking `df2[match(df[,1], df[,2]), -1] + df[,-1]`

Comment: @Vlo I think you mean something like `df1[, -1] + df2[match(df1$Type, df2$Type), -1]` as you need to match the correct columns. Though I was just editing this.

Comment: Yeah I meant to write `match(df1[,1],  df2[,1])` but reference by name is better

Answer (score 2):

You can just sum them and re-add the factor column.

```
df_tot <- df1 + df2
df_tot$Type = df1$Type
```

Comment: This is not correct as there is also a character/factor column

Comment: True, that's why the second line re-defines it.

Comment: But, based on the data provided by the OP, the datasets need to exclude the first column which was not shown in your code or at not found in the description.

Comment: You can sum the first column. The result will just be NA.

Comment: At least I am not getting the result, `df1+df2#
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: If the first column is a character, it will crash. If it's a factor, it'll return NAs.

Comment: But, we don't know whether it is a factor/character column from the OP's description

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the factor v char thing could be mentioned as a caveat. Despite how much I dislike them, factors are the default; and this works for that case. @DavidArenburg And yet it does work..? I just ran it.

Comment: @Frank I see what you mean. If we assume factors it will work in a sense.

Comment: @Frank Even if it is a factor, it gives an NA column with a warning.  (`Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors`).
It is easy to subset that factor column away from the calculation rather than having warnings and then reassign a column.

Comment: @akrun I guess I'm just about indifferent between the clutter of extra brackets/parentheses and getting a warning. The real solution (at least for this example) is to store numerical data in matrices, in which case the trusty vanilla `+` does work.

Comment: @Frank Yes, I respect your position.  I noticed in some cases where some previous posters complain even about some friendly warning.  `matrices` would be faster and more natural for this..

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `dplyr` + `magrittr`, if you want to go that route:

```
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")

df1 %>% select(-type) %>%
    add(df2 %>% select(-type)) %>%
    mutate(type = df1$type)
```

Note: this assumes `df1` and `df2` are ordered in the same manner.