# Final row with the sum of the previous results

Tags: r, sum, row

I want to generate a result that includes also a final row find the sum of the previous results. I have the following scenario.

Input data:

```
Group <- c("A","S","A","T","A","S")
Id <- c(25, 34, 28, 52, 3 ,5)
dataframe <- data.frame(Group, Id)
dataframe
```

Current function:

```
result = group_by(dataframe,Group) %>%
  summarise(q = n()) %>%
  mutate (Freq = round(q / sum(q), 3))

result
```

Current result:

```
   Group     q  Freq
  (fctr) (int) (dbl)
1      A     3 0.500
2      S     2 0.333
3      T     1 0.167
```

Dessired result:

```
   Group     q  Freq
  (fctr) (int) (dbl)
1      A     3 0.500
2      S     2 0.333
3      T     1 0.167
Total        6 1
```

How can I generate the total row?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you could use rbind(result,colSums(result). But R isn't really meant for this.. Excel would be your better option.

Comment: Since a total row isn't an observation, this is considered poor practice, as it will make doing anything with your data (plotting, summarizing) harder. If it's for presentation purposes there are ways, but you need to specify your medium.

Comment: `result["Total",] <- colSums(result)` given you have converted `result` to a regular `data.frame`, defined `row.names(result) = result$Group` and lastly dropped the `Group` col althogether `result$Group <- NULL`

Comment: @alistaire The purpose of adding a final row is to export the result with xtable to sweave

Comment: Gotcha. `knitr` is easier to work with than `Sweave`, though `xtable` can work with either. `knitr`'s built-in `kable` is worth a look, though, too, depending on what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you could get to in R would be something like this:

```
list(as.data.frame(result),"Total" = colSums(result[,-1]))
```

which would be preferred if you want to keep in within R. If you need a table for printing purposes (pdf,html) etc., using print.table for example, you would go with something like this:

```
result <- as.data.frame(result)
result["Total",] <- c(NA,colSums(result[,-1]))
```

and later replace the NA. This is however quite the dirty way to do it and makes it quite unusable for further calculations.

Also this was asked before, kind of: [How do I add a row to a data frame with totals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946873/how-do-i-add-a-row-to-a-data-frame-with-totals)

Comment: I have a further question. How could I do this if one of the columns is logical. For instance: `Group <- c("A","S","A","T","A","S")
Id <- c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE" ,"TRUE")

dataframe <- data.frame(Group, Id)
dataframe

result = group_by(dataframe,Group,Id) %>%
  summarise(q = n()) %>%
  mutate (Freq = round(q / nrow(dataframe), 3))

result

result <- as.data.frame(result)
result["Total",] <- c(NA,colSums(result[,-1]))` Is not possible because `Error in colSums(result[, -1]) : 'x' must be numeric`.
Is it still possible? Thank you

Comment: I answer my self. colSums(Filter(is.numeric, result))