# formatting table for saving in xlsx file

Tags: r

I want to format tables in xlsx format and save to xlsx file, and convert third column in percentage value.

```
    mtcars
df <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]

df <- janitor::adorn_totals(df)

wb <- loadWorkbook("blank_template.xlsx")
addWorksheet(wb, "tables")
writeDataTable(wb, "tables", df, tableStyle = "TablestyleMedium6")
```

I want to format a table like below and save it to an xlsx file.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `openxlsx` package.

Comment: What have you tried? See DT, formattable, gt, etc packages.

Comment: This can be achieved, but please give us a reproducible example. Are you asking two questions? How to manage your data to get these results and how to download as Excel to get this table formatting?

Comment: apologies for wrong question, i have just updated the question.
actually i am able to create workbook, worksheet etc but i am unable to for colour, percentage, in table to save as table in excel workbook

Comment: Do you have a workbook with prepared formatting? openxlsx help for `loadWorkbook` 
 is that it "returns a workbook object conserving styles and formatting of the original .xlsx file." Or do you want to create the formatting shown for a new workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way: `openxlsx` does need a fair bit of work but the great thing is you can generally achieve what you want.

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


df1 <- 
  mtcars[1:5,1:5] %>% 
  # to convert row names into a variable
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  # to enable a percentage format to be applied
  mutate(disp = disp/100)

df1 <- janitor::adorn_totals(df1)


wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "tables")

setColWidths(wb, 1, cols = 1, widths = 25)

writeData(wb, 1, df1)

header_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "#4F81BD", halign = "center", textDecoration = "bold", fontColour = "white")
addStyle(wb, 1, style = header_style, rows = 1, cols = 1:ncol(df1))

name_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "gray70", halign = "center", fontColour = "white")
addStyle(wb, 1, style = name_style, rows = 2 : nrow(df1), cols = 1)

percent_style <- createStyle(halign = "center", numFmt = "00%")
addStyle(wb, 1, style = percent_style, rows = 2 : nrow(df1), which(colnames(df1) == "disp"))

center_style <- createStyle(halign = "center")
addStyle(wb, 1, style = center_style, rows = 2 : nrow(df1), cols = which(!colnames(df1) %in% c("model", "disp")), gridExpand = TRUE)

total_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "yellow", halign = "center", fontColour = "black", fontSize = 14)
addStyle(wb, 1, style = total_style, rows = nrow(df1) + 1, cols = 1:ncol(df1))

saveWorkbook(wb, "openxlsx_mtcars_eg.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
[image]

Comment: My R studio is hanging on this line every time when i run and taking a lot of time.
writeData(wb, 1, df1)

Comment: i am just running this above sample data of mtcars and its hanging , did't test my own data

Comment: Not sure what to suggest: try restarting your computer, try on another computer, ensure that you have copied the code correctly, make sure you have up to date packages installed, do you have an up to date version of R and RStudio?. The code in the answer runs fine on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946873/add-row-to-a-data-frame-with-total-sum-for-each-column)

**1. Create a new row with `sum` for each `column`**

```
library(janitor)
df = adorn_totals(df, "row")
```

**2. Export to xlsx with the `openxlsx` or `xlsx` package**