# Using purrr to map a custom function to a dataframe with a variable length list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataframe that represents a presence / absence matrix (1 /0) for species in watersheds (rivers). The first column is the watershed. The remaining columns are the species. I need to merge some of the watershed rows together into one row. I have two functions that together return a modified dataframe with the merged watersheds. I have several groups of watersheds that I need to merge. The number of watersheds in each group varies.

**Question: How do I use `purrr` to map a custom function to a dataframe with a variable length list?**

I think `purrr()` should work but I am struggling to figure  out how to apply it. Below is a minimum working example that demonstrates the functions, followed by my ideas.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#missouri <- readRDS("provinces/data/state_fishes.rds")$Missouri

#motibble <- as_tibble(missouri, rownames = "watershed")

# Toy data
watershed <- c("Big", "Big_Piney", "Bourbeuse", "Gasconade", "Meramec")
Sp1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
Sp2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Sp3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Sp4 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
Sp5 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
Sp6 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Sp7 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
mo <- tibble(watershed, Sp1, Sp2, Sp3, Sp4, Sp5, Sp6, Sp7)

# Merge the rows sent from mod_df() 
# Reset any values greater than 1 to 1.
# Bind rows idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322272/3832941
merge_watersheds <- function(df = NULL, main = NULL) {
  df %>%
    bind_rows(
      summarise(
        .,
        across(where(is.numeric), sum),
        across(where(is.character), ~"total")
      )
    ) %>%
    filter(watershed == "total") %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ifelse(. >= 2, 1, .))) %>%
    mutate(watershed = replace(watershed, watershed == "total", main))
}

# Send the main and trib rows to be merged to merge_watersheds()
# Delete those rows, then bind the row returned from merge_watersheds()
# to remaining dataframe.
mod_df <- function(df = NULL, main = NULL, tribs = NULL) {
  tmp_df <- filter(df, watershed %in% c(main, tribs))
  wsheds <- merge_watersheds(tmp_df, main)
  tmp_df <- filter(df, !(watershed %in% c(main, tribs)))
  bind_rows(tmp_df, wsheds)
}

mo

# Before the functions
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>   watershed   Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Big           0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#> 2 Big_Piney     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
#> 3 Bourbeuse     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
#> 4 Gasconade     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 5 Meramec       0     0     0     1     0     0     1

mod_df(mo, main = "Meramec", tribs = c("Big", "Bourbeuse")) 

# Big and Borbeuse successfully merged into Meramec
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>   watershed   Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Big_Piney     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
#> 2 Gasconade     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 3 Meramec       0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In the `mod_df()` function above, `main` in the main watershed that will be retained as a row in the final data frame. `tribs` is a variable length vector with one to many tributaries that will be merged into the main watershed.

My first thought was to create a list of vectors. The `main` and `sub` variables passed to `mod_df()` could then be something like `main = vector[1]` and `tribs = vector[2:length(vector)]`. The vectors would identify the rows to be filtered from the dataframe.

```r
meramec = c("Meramec", "Big", "Bourbeuse")
gasconade = c("Gasconade", "Big_Piney")

merge_groups <- list(meramec, gasconade)

# This clearly doesn't work, but included here to show my
# non-working through process.

merged_mo <- purrr::map(mo, merge_groups, mod_df())
```

I assume that I would somehow pass the `mo` dataframe, the `merge_groups` list and the `mod_df()` function to `purrr:map()` but I can't figure out how.

I thought also of creating a list of dataframes but, at least in tibble form, I ended up with one `main` entry for each `trib` entry. The toy data above results in two "Meramec" values in a `main` column, one for each trib in the `tribs` column. Either way, I'm still unsure how to pass a dataframe with variable length tribs to `purrr::map`.

PS: I need the data in wide format for other purposes so I haven't tidy'd it up. I can do so and then pivot back to wide if that helps the process.

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I found a workable solution (see below) but I would still like to learn if this can be mapped or otherwise be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat different take. We can define groups in a named list for convenience and `enframe()` it to a tibble; joining it to the original frame adds a grouping variable `main`.

Added a few extra watersheds to the example data to check cases where not all of those are included in some group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data
watershed <- c("Big", "Big_Piney", "Bourbeuse", "Gasconade", "Meramec", "not_in_group", "another_not_in_group")
Sp1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
Sp2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
Sp3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
Sp4 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
Sp5 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Sp6 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Sp7 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
mo <- tibble(watershed, Sp1, Sp2, Sp3, Sp4, Sp5, Sp6, Sp7)
mo
#> # A tibble: 7 × 8
#>   watershed              Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Big                      0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#> 2 Big_Piney                1     0     0     1     0     0     0
#> 3 Bourbeuse                0     0     0     0     1     0     1
#> 4 Gasconade                1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 5 Meramec                  0     0     0     1     0     0     1
#> 6 not_in_group             0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 7 another_not_in_group     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Let's start with a simpler example, assuming all watersheds are part of a group `(left_join()` leaves out watersheds that are not present in `merge_groups`) :

```
merge_groups <- list(meramec = c("Meramec", "Big", "Bourbeuse"),
                     gasconade = c("Gasconade", "Big_Piney"))


enframe(merge_groups, name = "main", value = "watershed") %>% 
  unnest(watershed) %>% 
  left_join(mo, by = "watershed") %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sp"), ~ as.numeric(sum(.x) > 0)), .by = main)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 8
#>   main        Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 meramec       0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#> 2 gasconade     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

If some watersheds are not in a group but should remain in the resulting frame,  we first use `full_join` to keep all records, for watersheds not present in `merge_groups` we'll have `NA` for `main`.  We can then split by `!is.na(.$main)`, it creates 2 splits named `TRUE` and `FALSE`, with `map_at()` we can apply almost the same summarise expression as before to a relevant subset while keeping the other portion as-is. Then bind rows and clean up columns.

```r
enframe(merge_groups, name = "main", value = "watershed") %>% 
  unnest(watershed) %>% 
  full_join(mo, by = "watershed") %>% 
  split(!is.na(.$main)) %>% 
  map_at("TRUE", \(x) 
         summarise(x, across(starts_with("Sp"), ~ as.numeric(sum(.x) > 0)), .by = main) %>% 
           mutate(watershed = main)
         ) %>% 
  list_rbind() %>% 
  select(-main)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   watershed              Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 not_in_group             0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 2 another_not_in_group     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 3 meramec                  0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#> 4 gasconade                1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

---

Step-by-step walkthrough on what's happening during `as.numeric(sum(.x) > 0)`, though over columns for simplicity.

- count all `1`s with `sum()`
- check if that sum is `> 0`, result is boolean, `TRUE` / `FALSE`
- convert boolean values back to numeric (`1` / `0`)

```r
binary_sample <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C,
   0,  0,  0,
   0,  0,  1,
   0,  1,  1,
   1,  1,  1)

binary_sample %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(`sum()`                            = sum(across(A:C)),
         `sum() > 0`                        = sum(across(A:C)) > 0,
         `as.numeric(sum() > 0)` = as.numeric(sum(across(A:C)) > 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       A     B     C `sum()` `sum() > 0` `as.numeric(sum() > 0)`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>                         <dbl>
#> 1     0     0     0       0 FALSE                             0
#> 2     0     0     1       1 TRUE                              1
#> 3     0     1     1       2 TRUE                              1
#> 4     1     1     1       3 TRUE                              1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like your answer because I was unfamiliar with enframe and you reminded me that I will have to account for watersheds without tribs (not in a group). I hope to learn more about how map() works so let me see if other interesting answers come along before deciding what works best overall for me.

Comment: I can parse all of the code except for `sum(.x) > 0`. I read that as sum values and include results greater than zero. At least one of the columns has two `1` values so the sum should be 2. Yet, the results are consistently `1`, as they should be. I haven't figured out how this works.  Your code worked very well for me when I applied it to my full data  set. Thank you.

Comment: It converts a numeric vector to logical and when passed through `as.numeric`, back to numeric so youd have `0` / `1` values instead of `FALSE` / `TRUE`. Added a small example explaining those steps.

Comment: Ah, of course. I put the "logical" inside the parenthenses instead of outside.  Thanks for the explanation, your update to the code, and your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a non-`map()` solution using `pluck()` from the `purrr` package. It's not elegant but it works.

I trimmed down the `mod_df()` function to return only the merged main watershed. I created named lists of my watershed groups to merge, then pluck the main and tribs to pass to `mod_df()` inside a `for()` loop. I made a new dataframe to collect the results.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data
watershed <- c("Big", "Big_Piney", "Bourbeuse", "Gasconade", "Meramec")
Sp1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
Sp2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Sp3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
Sp4 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
Sp5 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
Sp6 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Sp7 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
mo <- tibble(watershed, Sp1, Sp2, Sp3, Sp4, Sp5, Sp6, Sp7)

# Merge the rows sent from mod_df() 
# Reset any values greater than 1 to 1.
# Bind rows idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322272/3832941
merge_watersheds <- function(df = NULL, main = NULL) {
  df %>%
    bind_rows(
      summarise(
        .,
        across(where(is.numeric), sum),
        across(where(is.character), ~"total")
      )
    ) %>%
    filter(watershed == "total") %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ifelse(. >= 2, 1, .))) %>%
    mutate(watershed = replace(watershed, watershed == "total", main))
}

# Send the main and trib rows to be merged to merge_watersheds()
# return only the merged watershed result
mod_df <- function(df = NULL, main = NULL, tribs = NULL) {
  tmp_df <- filter(df, watershed %in% c(main, tribs))
  merge_watersheds(tmp_df, main)
}

meramec = list(main = "Meramec", tribs = c("Big", "Bourbeuse"))
gasconade = list(main = "Gasconade", tribs = c("Big_Piney"))
merge_groups <- list(meramec, gasconade)

new_mo <- tibble()
for (i in 1:length(merge_groups)) {
  watershed <- mod_df(
    mo, 
    main = pluck(merge_groups, i, "main"), 
    tribs = pluck(merge_groups, i, "tribs")
  ) 
  new_mo <- bind_rows(new_mo, watershed)
}
new_mo

# Success
#> # A tibble: 2 × 8
#>   watershed   Sp1   Sp2   Sp3   Sp4   Sp5   Sp6   Sp7
#>   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Meramec       0     0     0     1     1     1     1
#> 2 Gasconade     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Created on 2023-10-03 with reprex v2.0.2